# Finding the optimal binary matrix

Tags: matrices, optimization, linear-programming, integer-programming, binary-programming

Let $a$ be an $n \times 1$ positive vector, $b$ be an $m \times 1$ positive vector, and $X$ be an $m \times n$ matrix where $x_{ij} \in \{0,1\}$. I want to find the $X$ that minimizes $\sum_{i=1}^m v_i$, where $v = b-Xa$, subject to

- summation of each column in $X$ should be either $0$ or $1$
- $v_i \geq 0$

Comment: This looks like a [linear programming](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming) problem in disguise

Comment: Thanks for your note. I have edited the question.

Comment: @littleO question is refined now to my requirement.

Comment: Basically there are $m$ bins of sizes $b_i$, and $n$ items of sizes $a_i$, and you have to put (some of) the items in the bins in such a way as to completely fill the bins but with as little waste as possible. The location of the 1 in a column of $X$ says which bin an item goes into (if any).

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Exactly! that's good way to visualize it. An extra bonus is to optimize it in a such a way to be able to decide to remove extra bins "having zeros rows in $X$" while being able to accommodate all $a_i$ in the remaining bins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\rm v := X a - b$, where $\rm a, b$ are given positive vectors. Hence,

$$1_m^{\top} \mathrm v = 1_m^{\top} \mathrm X \, \mathrm a - 1_m^{\top} \mathrm b = \mbox{tr} (\mathrm a 1_m^{\top} \mathrm X) - 1_m^{\top} \mathrm b = \langle 1_m \mathrm a^{\top}, \mathrm X \rangle - 1_m^{\top} \mathrm b$$

Thus, we have the following *binary* **integer program** (IP) in $\mathrm X \in \{0,1\}^{m \times n}$

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & \langle 1_m \mathrm a^{\top}, \mathrm X \rangle\\ \text{subject to} & 0_n^{\top} \leq 1_m^{\top} \mathrm X \leq 1_n^{\top}\\ & \mathrm X \mathrm a \geq \mathrm b\\ & \mathrm X \in \{0,1\}^{m \times n}\end{array}$$

[Vectorizing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)), we obtain

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & (\mathrm a \otimes 1_m)^{\top} \mbox{vec} (\mathrm X) \rangle\\ \text{subject to} & 0_n \leq (\mathrm I_n \otimes 1_m^{\top}) \,\mbox{vec} (\mathrm X) \leq 1_n\\ & (\mathrm a^{\top} \otimes \mathrm I_m) \, \mbox{vec} (\mathrm X) \geq \mathrm b\\ & \mbox{vec} (\mathrm X) \in \{0,1\}^{m n}\end{array}$$

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. Can you guide me through a numeric example as I am new to the IP concept. And kindly recommend to me an IP solver that can consume the procedure program you provided.

Comment: @Mustafa If you use Python, try [PuLP](https://www.coin-or.org/PuLP/). Use `LpInteger` to force the decision variables to be integral.

Comment: @Mustafa In MATLAB, use function [intlinprog](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/intlinprog.html).

Comment: I tried implementing the intlinprog function. It works fine only if you remove the integer restriction. I posted the programming question here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43938726/optimal-binary-matrix-solution) . Am I going wrong somewhere with coding the solution?

Comment: I discovered I made a mistake in the question. the definition of v should be v=b-Xa. How this would modify our integer program IP? I have modified the question now.

Comment: @Mustafa Just switch the signs of $\rm a$ and $\rm b$.

Comment: Perfect the code is fine now. Many thanks for your patience and sincere support.  Best regards.

Comment: the program works great on small vectors a and b. However, when trying vectors with 200 elements or more, the matlab function run out of memory.

Comment: I came across multi- Knapsacks problem concept and found matching my problem. Is there a way to avoid the big memory requirement when having large input?

Comment: @Mustafa Naive exhaustive search would require evaluating $2^{200} \approx 10^{60}$ candidate matrices! You may want to try using the [GNU Linear Programming Kit](https://www.gnu.org/software/glpk/), which is written in C. You can also try [PuLP](https://www.coin-or.org/PuLP/).

Comment: Thanks! I will try them and give my feedback. Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that since you are summing the end results, $B$ has no bearing on the choice of $X$, and that leaves you minimizing
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^m a_i x_{ji}
 = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i \left( \sum_{j=1}^m x_{ji} \right),
$$
so you should set to 1 all $x_{ji}$ in the rows, where $a_j<0$ and otherwise, set the rest of $x_{ji}=0$.

Comment: Thanks for your response... I have edited the question to have $a_i$>0 and $b_i$>0. In this case, B **has** bearing on the choice of **X** because the optimum solution would only happen when AX=B. Could you help in this case please?